# Symfony and MySQL/Doctrine: manage a todo lists with todos that may relate to many different entities: tables or fields or many-to-any?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Say I have to manage some lists with some todos in each.

But each todo can be related to otherr entities: say a user (call him), or a document (say edit it), or any other entity managed by my app.

I see only two solutions to manage these relationships:

1. Use a separate table for each relation type (and so I will came up with tables like `todo_users`, `todo_documents` and so on)
2. Use dedicated fields in the `todos` table (and so I will have fields like `too_id`, `todo_list`, `relates_to_user`, `relates_to_document`, ecc.)

**QUESTION #1**: the two solutions may have different performances on very large datasets? Or are they equivalent?

**QUESTION #2**: Is there a better approach I can follow?

Doctrine doesn't support it, but is there a way to build an `todo-to-any` relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Try to store things in #2 fashion will result in a mess soon or later. Some of the problems you can face (I'm sure that will be others that now I can't see or remember of)

- Everytime you need to add a relationship with a new entity, you need to add a column: only one column at a time is "significant" as, I imagine, only one todo_list can belong to other entity.
- (direct consequence of point above) You need to control "programmatically" that **only** one column at a time has `true` value and that **at least** one column has `true` value (that can become pretty difficult to guarantee if you "bypass" your application API and go direct onto db (`relates_to_*` fields here are treated like booleans to indicate foreign key "membership"; if they are just foreign keys, you need to guarantee the same constraints but instead of `true` value, substitute `not null`)
- If `relates_to_*` are booleans you need to store an extra field with foreign key: this is not possibile in doctrine (and in sql in general) as you can't declare a foreign key referencing more than one table
- You have an amount of useless "noise data" for each record: if this application runs for ten users this would not be a problem at all, otherwise it will be for sure.

I suggest to take a look at [doctrine inheritance mappings](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html): this is the solution to your problem and is handled "under the hood" directly from doctrine itself.

Comment: Not booleans, but `null` or with the value of the ID of the entity to which the list refers to: so, if the list refers to a Document, the field `references_to_document` will have a value of, say, `3`, where `3` is the Document ID. This way I can mange all with Doctrine... But I don't understand well how to apply the mapped superclasses: in this case basically I will use the solution #1 I figured... Am I right? What about the possibility to use an `todo-to-any` relationship? Is it possible to achieve in some ways?

Comment: @Aerendir read what I wrote: it's the same if no bools but ids. BTW with inheritance you can achieve what you need: no todo-to-any but todo-to-superclasstable than superclasstable to any of other tables (handled directly and straightforward by doctrine)